# Remove duplicates in an array and have its second value added to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to convert:

```
[["val1", "1"], ["val2", "2"], ["val1", "3"], ["val3", "4"], ["val2", "5"], ["val2", "6"]]
```

to:

```
[["val1", ["1", "3"]], ["val2", ["2", "5", "6"]], ["val3", ["4"]]
```

Duplicates of the first value (`"val1"`) of the subarrays are removed, and their second values (`"1"` and `"3"`) are put together in an array.

I could call `uniq` on the array, but that only fixes half the problem. I gave it my best crack:

- Store the first value (we can call value a) of the 2d array into
  another 2d array and calling .uniq on the new array.
- The new 2d array has an empty array in value b.
- Then loop through the new array with an if statement comparing the
  original arrays value a to the new arrays value a. If value a from
  the original array matches val a from the new array add its b value
  to the new arrays b value array.

This was my approach but there is most likely an easier approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[["val1", "1"], ["val2", "2"], ["val1", "3"], ["val3", "4"], ["val2", "5"], ["val2", "6"]]
.group_by(&:first).map{|k, a| [k, a.map(&:last)]}
# => [["val1", ["1", "3"]], ["val2", ["2", "5", "6"]], ["val3", ["4"]]]
```

Comment: Let say the input is `[["val1", "1"], ["val1", "1"]]`, the output is incorrect I think, add `uniq` after `a.map(&:last)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to accomplish the same:

```
ary.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |i, h|  
  h[i.first] << i.last 
end.to_a
#=> [["val1", ["1", "3"]], ["val2", ["2", "5", "6"]], ["val3", ["4"]]]
```

We use a `Hash` which will initialise the keys with empty array, and it helps in the block to push the values into the array without having to do nil check.