# Wrap an href link around strings in a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
[["val1", ["The cat", "3"]], ["val2", ["Big", "Another", "6"]], ["val3", ["343"]]
```

made by modifying another array from my question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553136/remove-duplicates-in-an-array-and-have-its-second-value-added-to-an-array) using this code:

```
array.group_by(&:first).map{|k, a| [k, a.map(&:last)]}
```

The answer to this question may be added to the code above or just use the array given.

I'm trying to turn the array into this:

```
[["val1", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/the-cat'>The cat</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/red-foo'>Red Foo</a>"]], ["val2", [""<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/big'>Big</a>", ""<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/another'>Another</a>", ""<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/6'>6</a>"]], ["val3", [""<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/joe'>Joe</a>"]]
```

A link is wrapped around the arrays' array values.

```
"<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/" + value_parameterized + "'>" + original_value + "</a>"
```

- It starts with a string which makes up the start of the `a` tag.
- Then the tricky part of copying the value and calling `parameterize` on it and placing it after the first string.
- Another string is added.
- Then the original string (or value) of the array is added.
- Lastly the end of the `a` tag is added.

Copying the value and parameterizing it then passing it back in the right place is where I have no hope.

In the end I'll be turning the nested arrays into strings like so:

```
["val1", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/the-cat'>The cat</a>, <a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/red-foo'>Red Foo</a>"]
```

If it's easier to modify or create a new array and have the second value be a string then I'll be super happy.

I can't use Rails' `link_to`.

Comment: Where are "Red Foo" and "Joe" coming from? I don't see that in the original array.

Comment: I changed the values to show the `.parameterize` better. And shortened it so It wasn't bloated with href links in the end result example. Its still the same 'type' of array I maybe should've said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruteforce way is,

```
array = [["val1", ["The cat", "3"]], ["val2", ["Big", "Another", "6"]], ["val3", ["343"]]
array.each_with_object([]) do |val, out|
    result = [val.first]
    result << val.second.each_with_object([]) { |v, s_out| s_out << "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/#{v.parameterize}'>#{v}</a>" } 
    out << result
end

# => [["val1", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/the-cat'>The cat</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/3'>3</a>"]], ["val2", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/big'>Big</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/another'>Another</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/6'>6</a>"]], ["val3", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/343'>343</a>"]]]
```

One liner,

```
array.each_with_object([]) { |val, out| out << [val.first, val.second.each_with_object([]) { |v, s_out| s_out << "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/#{v.parameterize}'>#{v}</a>" } ] }
```

**OR**

[Ruby#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), creates a new array.

To alter the same array, you could use [Ruby#map!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) or [Ruby#collect!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-collect-21)

```
array = [["val1", ["The cat", "3"]], ["val2", ["Big", "Another", "6"]], ["val3", ["343"]]]
array.collect! { |value| [value.first, value.second.collect! {|link| "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/#{link.parameterize}'>#{link}</a>" } ] }

#=> [["val1", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/the-cat'>The cat</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/3'>3</a>"]], ["val2", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/big'>Big</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/another'>Another</a>", "<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/6'>6</a>"]], ["val3", ["<a href='/guides/{#guide}/pages/343'>343</a>"]]]
```

**Benchmark results**

```
                 user     system      total        real
each_with_object 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000610)
collect!         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000379)
```

Comment: Great answer! I went with the one liner in the first option. Do you recommend one or think one is faster than the other?

Comment: You should use the second option obviously. collect! uses the same array. Check the Benchmark results updated to the answer.